# what changes should be made to generate the following pattern on screen? ***** **** *** ** *

Tags: c

What changes should be made to generate the following pattern on the screen?

```
*****
****
***
**
*
```

**Code**

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int n, m;

    for (n = 1; n <= 5; n++)
    {
        for (m = 1; m <= 5; m++)
            printf("*");
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: What does it generate now?

Comment: What are your own thoughts? This seems like a homework dump. But as a hint: Change the initial value of `m`

Comment: You only need to change one character in the source code.

Comment: Output : ***** ***** ***** ***** *****

Comment: @IanAbbott: Not really. If it were this triangle: * ** *** **** *****, then you would be right

Comment: @ArmenTsirunyan I mean changing a different character to the one you thought I meant.

Comment: @IanAbbott: Ah, I see it now :)

Comment: @IanAbbott changing only one character? WTF! I can't find it :(

Comment: @DavidRanieri. To control the number of iterations, you can change either the condition, or the initial value :)

Comment: @ArmenTsirunyan yes, but this requires changing more than one character, isn't it?

Comment: @DavidRanieri. If you change the condition - yes. If you change the initial value for m, you just need to replace int m = 1  int m = <won't tell>

Comment: @ArmenTsirunyan OMG :)))))

Answer (score 2):

This most probably seems like a homework question. So here's a hint:

The following code prints the pattern in reverse:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    for (int n = 1; n <= 5; n++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
        {
            printf("*");
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

The rest should be easy, Good luck!

Comment: I have made some changes to reverse it but not getting this ***** **** *** ** *

Answer (score 1):

Well, the outside loop, the one with variable n is iterating through your rows, because each iteration of the outer loop ends with printing a newline charactee.

What you do inside that outer loop is completely independent from the value of the outer loop counter, therefore, each of the 5 rows will be IDENTICAL and therefore will not draw you a triangle.

Enumerate your rows 1 2 3 4 5 in your head, then formulate exactly what needs to be printed on row number n. Translate your formulation into c and voila.